# How to store http result in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

couldn't find answers from other questions.

I'm trying to get data from a web service, and then draw a chart and display a table below it.

If I put the datatable inside the .then function it throws in an error. So what I'm thinking is to store the result in a json variable and load it using `fromSource`.

The problem right now is I can see the `def.promise`, but when I try to access the .value, it shows 'undefined'.

any idea?

```
app.controller('abc', function($scope, $q, $http){
 var def = $q.defer();

$http.get(API).then(function(result){
  def.resolve(result);
  //draw a chart
});
console.log(def.promise.$$state.value); //returns undefined. 
console.log(def.promise); 
//returns:
//d {$$state: Object, then: function, catch: function, finally: function}$$state: Objectstatus: 1value: Array[39]0: //Object1: Object2:

 $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(angular.toJson(def.promise.$$state.value));
});
```

Comment: What is the error you get when it's in `.then`?

Comment: You don't have to create your own asynchronous code with $q, $http calls are asynchronous by default

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out...

Instead of using fromSource for referencing data for the datatable, you can use fromFnPromise.